# Creating whisker plots from grouped pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset of values arriving in 5min timestamped intervals that I'm visualising grouped by hours of day, like this[image: hours_group]

I want to turn this into a whisker/box plot for the added information. However, the implementations of `matplotlib`, `seaborn` and `pandas` of this plot all want an array of raw data to compute the plot's contents themselves.

Is there a way to create whisker plots from **pre-computed/grouped** mean, median, std and quartiles? I would like to avoid reinventing the wheel with a comparatively inefficient grouping algorithm to build per-day datasets just for this.

---

This is some code to produce toy data and a version of the current plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# some toy data in a 15-day range
data = [1.5+np.sin(x)*5 for x in np.arange(0, 403.3, .1)]
s = pd.Series(data=data, index=pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-01-15', freq='5min'))

s.groupby(s.index.hour).mean().plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

---

Adding to @Quang Hoang's solution: You can use `hlines()` to display the median as well:

```
axis.bar(data.index, data['q75'] - data['q25'], bottom=data['q25'], width=wd)
axis.hlines(y=data['median'], xmin=data.index-wd/2, xmax=data.index+wd/2, color='black', linewidth=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything for that. But you can create a whisker plot fairly simply with two plot command:

```
# precomputed data:
data = (s.groupby(s.index.hour)
         .agg(['mean','std','median',
               lambda x: x.quantile(.25),
               lambda x: x.quantile(.75)])
       )
data.columns = ['mean','std','median','q25','q75']


# plot the whiskers with `errorbar` from `mean` and `std`
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))
ax.errorbar(data.index,data['mean'], 
            yerr=data['std']*1.96, 
            linestyle='none',
            capsize=5
            )

 # plot the boxes with `bar` at bottoms from quantiles
ax.bar(data.index, data['q75']-data['q25'], bottom=data['q25'])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's a very cool approach to the problem! Could you tell me why you're scaling the `std` by 1.96 for the error bars?

Comment: @bhnn that’s the 95% of the normal distribution. I used it for illustration only.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you clarify?